# Having trouble with concat in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error in MySql:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `msgBoardGetComments2`(

IN _StoryID INT,
IN _RowNum INT

)
BEGIN

DECLARE _sql VARCHAR(1000);

   SET _sql := CONCAT('SELECT c.CommentText, c.CommentDate, a.UserName
      FROM comments c
      LEFT JOIN accounts a
             ON c.UserID = a.UserID
             LEFT JOIN stories s
                    ON c.StoryID = s.StoryID
      WHERE c.StoryID = ',_StoryID, '
      ORDER BY c.CommentDate DESC
      LIMIT 10
      OFFSET ', _RowNum);

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @_sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

END

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be receiving that error when `_RowNum` is `NULL`. If this is the case, you can try adding an `IF` condition to optionally include the `OFFSET _RowNum` if the `_RowNum` is `NULL`. You can test this by printing your query before execution:

```
SELECT _sql;
--PREPARE stmt1 FROM @_sql;
--EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Also, I haven't seen the use of an underscore (`_`) for variable assignment, perhaps that may also be playing a role in this?

Comment: njk, thank you for trying to help me out.  When I call the function with a number value for _RowNum, it still gives the same error.  Also I have been using variables with and underscore for a while and never had any issue, so I dont think that is part of the problem.  I am a bit new to these type of dynamic queries, so I cant really figure what the problem is

Comment: @user1675852 If you are just needing to return a result set, I would recommend you use a function, not a stored procedure.

Comment: Its part of a dynamic site where I will be using the same Proc to load comments for different posts on several different sites, so it seems to make sense to me to keep it as a procedure.  i did figure it out and it was pretty simple.  I just overlooked it being unfamiliar with dynamic queries.  I just had to put the @ in front of the _sql in the Set statement and I didnt have to declare _sql either.  Thanks for your input.